# Python can't overwrite file

Tags: python, file

I am reading from a file, adding a line to it and then saving it back.
In C# this would work - But not in Python. Can anyone tell me why?

```
f = "blogs/%s.comment" % blogtitle
if os.path.isfile(f):
    temp = file(f).readlines()
    temp.append(comment)

    overr = open(f, "w") #line 13
    for l in temp: overr.write(l)
```

The error I get is `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` at line 13

I am running this file as a .wsgi in Apache and have 775 permissions in the folder where the file is stored.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the file after you had opened it the first time, do it as follows:

```
f = "blogs/%s.comment" % blogtitle
if os.path.isfile(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as fl:
        temp = fl.readlines()
        temp.append(comment)

    with open(f, "w") as fl:
        for l in temp: fl.write(l)
```

Comment: First, `f` is a string, not a file. `f.close()` won't work. Second, you should really open the file with a `with` statement (both times).

Comment: @Saphire, I updated my answer. Did you try it after the update?

Comment: @Saphire, Are you sure you have permission to __write__ to that file/directory?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't `close` the file. You should open the file in a `with` statement to handle closing. Also, it's simpler and more efficient to just open the file in append mode instead of reading the whole thing and writing it back:

```
path = "blogs/%s.comment" % blogtitle
with open(path, 'a') as f:
    f.write(comment)
```